# Deleting, Moving pre defined components from template in Adobe AEM

Tags: aem

I have requirement where, in template we will have some list of components by default. But the requirement is, author can delete,move these components in the page.

We are using sightly and I have used

```
<div sly data-sly-resource="${'sample' @ resourceType='sampleapp/components/content/sample'}" />
```

This is working fine. But I am not sure how do to delete and move this component.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a template/component in which you include a specific component then it cannot be moved or deleted. It will show the delete option but after refresh it will be there again (not configured). The things that can be moved are components placed within parsyses.

To create template which has predefined components that can be then moved around you need to base your structure on parsyses. Place your predefined components within the **templates** parsyses - within the templates jcr:content. Remember that template is nothing else then a predefined content node.

See the example in which the survey-template has predefined content:
[image]